# Structured Haskell Mode fails to install

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal

I am trying to update my structured haskell mode using the cabal install command.  Unfortunately, it's failing

```
obelix:~ rk$ cabal install structured-haskell-mode
Warning: The install command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-install
command or the legacy v1-install alias as new-style projects will become the
default in the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot
replicate a working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Resolving dependencies...
Starting     structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0
Building     structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0
Failed to install structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0
Build log ( /Users/rk/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0-BtZnu5PUgZA64b8d6lKBIV.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/m7/cw4w1yc11pv_t25pmlyqc4qm0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-1494/structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0'
Configuring structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Preprocessing executable 'structured-haskell-mode' for structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0..
Building executable 'structured-haskell-mode' for structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, dist/build/structured-haskell-mode/structured-haskell-mode-tmp/Main.o )

src/Main.hs:165:18: error:
    • The constructor ‘Deriving’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
    • In the pattern: Deriving _ ds@(_ : _)
      In the pattern: Just (Deriving _ ds@(_ : _))
      In a case alternative:
          Just (Deriving _ ds@(_ : _))
            -> [spanHSE
                  (show "InstHeads")
                  "InstHeads"
                  (SrcSpan
                     (srcSpanFilename start)
                     (srcSpanStartLine start)
                     (srcSpanStartColumn start)
                     (srcSpanEndLine end)
                     (srcSpanEndColumn end)) |
                  Just (IRule _ _ _ (IHCon (SrcSpanInfo start _) _)) <- [listToMaybe
                                                                           ds],
                  Just (IRule _ _ _ (IHCon (SrcSpanInfo end _) _)) <- [listToMaybe
                                                                         (reverse ds)]]
    |
165 |            Just (Deriving _ ds@(_:_)) ->
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/m7/cw4w1yc11pv_t25pmlyqc4qm0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-1494/structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
structured-haskell-mode-1.1.0-BtZnu5PUgZA64b8d6lKBIV failed during the
building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

It seems that it's calling the `Deriving` constructor with the wrong number of arguments. Any suggestions for a quick fix?

Comment: The new argument is probably a *deriving strategy*

Comment: I know nothing about any of this, but did you try the "new-style" project/commands that it recommends?

Comment: There is a similar issue open on the github repo: https://github.com/chrisdone/structured-haskell-mode/issues/160 but the project hasn't seen much activity in the last 7 months or so.  I hope it's not dead as it is super cool Emacs mode for Haskell.